# Having some problems with Array Lists and adding values. Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I was working on this problem using arrays and array lists, and then I want to sort the array list to that the numbers the user enters are in ascending over. When I try to run this, I get two error codes, 1: the period on the list.add(num1); is not recognized, and then the other error code is that the Arrays.sort(list); is not recognized, I honestly have no clue what to do, I searched the web all over and could not find anything, this is the sole reason I made this account xD. Please help!!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class randomArrayList{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 5;
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter 5 numbers: ");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        list.add(num1);
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        list.add(num2);
        int num3 = input.nextInt();
        list.add(num3);
        int num4 = input.nextInt();
        list.add(num5);
        int num5 = input.nextInt();
        list.add(num5);
        Arrays.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please beware that `Scanner#nextInt` won't read the dangling new line left in the input buffer

Comment: can not add `list.add(num5);` before you have declared the variable.  I think you want to add `num4`

Comment: `Arrays.sort(list);` as the name implies is for sorting Arrays.

Comment: Yeah, use `Collections.sort(list)` instead.

Comment: So why does Collections work instead of Arrays? because it's only one array list instead of many?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Sorry your comment is lost on me.  Please explain

Comment: @ScaryWombat I FINALLY FOUND OUT WHAT YOU MEANT THANK YOU :DDDDDDD!!!!!!

Comment: _"So why does Collections work instead of Arrays?"_ — your `list` is _not_ an Array, it is a `List` that just so happens to be backed by an array. Arrays.sort works on actual arrays, like an `Integer[] nums`, while Collections.sort works on any kind of orderable Collection. A "List" is one of the collection types. Side tip — you should declare `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);` … your `list` is a "List", and you are just choosing an `ArrayList` as the implementation you're going to use for your `List`

Comment: @reyferm - see "[What is difference between array and ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1552742/17300)" — It's about `.net` but the principles are the same, and there are answers on that question that talk about Java.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want

Note

can not add `list.add(num5);` before you have declared the variable. I think you want to add `num4`

and

`Arrays.sort(list);` as the name implies is for sorting Arrays.

use `Collections.sort(list)` instead

```
int n = 5;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter 5 numbers: ");
int num1 = input.nextInt();
list.add(num1);
int num2 = input.nextInt();
list.add(num2);
int num3 = input.nextInt();
list.add(num3);
int num4 = input.nextInt();
list.add(num4);
int num5 = input.nextInt();
list.add(num5);
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

Although a cleaner way would to be use a loop

Comment: Thank you!!! I think I understand it now, I'm just lost on why Collections works but Arrays doesn't.

Comment: Arrays.sort works on Arrays, Collections.sort works on Collections.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking, but could you please explain to me the difference between the two?

Comment: What don't you understand?  They are two different pieces on code working on different type of Objects.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just was misunderstanding that I could use the Arrays method to help me with this, but I get what it is now :).

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how to accept it, but I upvoted it, and it said that I can't upvote some of them because this is such a new account.