# In java while using 'new' keyword why we can't change size if it allocate memory at run time and what with ArrayList how it can change its size?

Tags: arrays, arraylist

In java when 'new' keyword is used, it allocate memory at run time so while assigning value into array like  "int nums[]=new int[10];"then why we can not change the size again, and what happens with ARRAYLIST which gives a liberty to do it? please elaborate it if possible?

I supposed in static array we can also change its size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between array and ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552742/what-is-difference-between-array-and-arraylist)

Comment: Eventhough the linked question is about .net data structures, the principle is the same ...